# Updating tableview view for a chat application

Tags: ios

I'm implementing real time chat in my app using firebase and and if the keyboard is shown and the user sends me 10 messages in a row, his messages will eventually start hiding behind my keyboard or go out below the tableview view (if the keyboard isn't shown).  I believe this has to do with adjusting the view to adjust to the number of rows within the tableview. Ultimately, I need the latest cell to be right above the textfield (whether the keyboard is shown or not) every time I send a message or receive the latest message.  Any tips?  I took a look at firechat on github and they don't seem to have any code for this: https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios/blob/master/Firechat/ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveView:[notification userInfo] up:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveView:[notification userInfo] up:NO];
}

- (void)moveView:(NSDictionary*)userInfo up:(BOOL)up
{
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&animationCurve];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&animationDuration];

    // Get the correct keyboard size to we slide the right amount.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    int y = keyboardFrame.size.height * (up ? -1 : 1);
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, y);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: You can scroll the tableView programatically to the required cell.

Comment: Oh really.  Is there a standard method to do this or does it have to be custom?

Comment: Check the [Scrolling the Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:) section. Also you can try to set content offset value as at a general scroll view.